# Get VU of VSXu artiste with C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, dll, base-address, cheat-engine

this is my code so far:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace std;



int main() {

    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL,TEXT("Vovoid VSXu Artiste 0.4.0 [Windows 64-bit]"));
    if (hWnd == 0) {
        cerr << "Cannot find window "<< endl;
    }
    else {
        DWORD pId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pId);
        cout << "Found Window at "<<pId << endl;
        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pId);
        HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("sound.rtaudio.dll"));

        if (hProc == 0) {
            cerr << "Cannot open process." << endl;
        }else if(hModule==0){
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            cerr << "could not find Module -> error: " <<error<< endl;
        }
        else {
            float val = 0;
            int addr = 0x04D40000 + 0x19098;//should be sound.rtaudio.dll+ 0x19098
            while(TRUE){
                int suc = ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)addr, &val, (DWORD)sizeof(val), NULL);
                if (suc > 0) {
                    cout << "Success reading " << val << " of " << hex << addr << endl;
                    system("cls");
                }
                else {
                    DWORD error = GetLastError();
                    cerr << "fail " << error << endl;
                }
            }


        }
        CloseHandle(hProc);
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to read the VU (sound card volume) value of the VSXu Artiste sound visualisation programm with C++ and with the help of Cheat Engine. It works perfectly fine with `ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)addr, &val, (DWORD)sizeof(val), NULL);` until you re-open VSXu. This is pretty obvious, because the address of my value in Cheat Engine is "sound.rtaudio.dll+19098" and the DLL loads to a "random" address.
In Cheat Engine you can simply press Ctrl+G in the memory viewer and type the name of the DLL to find its base address. I have already tried the GetModuleHandle method in C++ without success:

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("sound.rtaudio.dll"));
```

Has anyone an idea how to get the base address of the dll with C++?

Cheat Engine screenshot:  http://oi57.tinypic.com/331k7sw.jpg

Kind regards,

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I suppose because you are calling GetModuleHandle within your own process. The solution you can try is to use:

[GetModuleInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it will return base address in MODULEINFO as:

> lpBaseOfDll
>
> The load address of the module.

To get process and module handle you can use sample code from here:[Enumerating All Modules For a Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Isn't there an easyer way or do I have to cycle through all the modules to find the proper module handle? Or is there even a more intelligent way to find the base address of the DLL (like AOB scan)?

Comment: @Trirop if you ask for oneliner - then I dont think so, also you can verify your base address by using process explorer from sysinternals, it will show you for each process, a list of modules - you will have to add column for base address.